# Moment giving wrong result when comparing dates

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am attempting to compare 2 dates and I am getting an error.

These are my functions:

```
const validateDate = (date: string): Moment => {
  return moment(`${moment().year()}/${date}`);
};

export const themes: Theme[] = [{
  siteCode: '',
  costCenter: '',
  theme: 'spring',
  bannerImage: 'spring.jpg',
  cssOverride: 'springThemeStyles.scss',
  endDate: moment(validateDate('6/19')).toDate(),
  startDate: moment(validateDate('3/20')).toDate()
}];

export const getActiveTheme = (): any => {
  const now = moment().toDate();

  console.log(now); // Thu Mar 19 2020 21:56:10 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
  console.log(themes[0].startDate); // Fri Mar 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
  console.log(themes[0].startDate >= now); // true

  return themes.map((t: Theme) => {
    if (t.startDate >= now) { // this is always true I don't know why
      if (t.theme.toLowerCase() === 'spring') {
        return require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss');
      }

      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

I don't get why the condition `if (t.startDate >= now) {...}` is always `true`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fri Mar 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0600 is greater than Thu Mar 19 2020 21:56:10 GMT-0600 so the condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because **startDate** is on the **Fri Mar 20 2020** and **now** is on the **Thu Mar 19 2020** so it's clear that **startDate >= now** should be true

Since you have set your **startDate** to the 20th, **startDate >= now** would be false when **now** would be on 21th